# Sketch - Joining two separate paths

Tags: shapes, path, sketch-app, pen-tool, anchor-point

How do I connect point A to point Z? Currently, when I select Anchor point A, it tries to connect point A & B (as you can see in image 2).

[image: image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select both shapes and go to menu: **Layer -> Paths -> Join**

[image]

And two shapes will be joined.

Comment: So you can't actually choose what anchor points join? It automatically assumes you want to join the closest points.